# errors by create js file that contains jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I created a file is called: jquery.js:

```
$(document).ready(function{
   jQuery('#sortable1, #sortable2')
     .sortable(
     {'connectWith':'.connectedSortable',
     'dropOnEmpty':true,
     'scroll':true,
      items: "li:not(.emptyMessage)",
      receive: function(event, ui) {
             //hide empty message on receiver
             $('li.emptyMessage', this).hide();

             //show empty message on sender if applicable
             if($('li:not(.emptyMessage)', ui.sender).length == 0){
                 $('li.emptyMessage', ui.sender).show();
             } else {
                 $('li.emptyMessage', ui.sender).hide();
             }            
         }

    });
});
```

In my `index.html.erb`, I have:

**I ADDED THE FIRST SCRIPT SRC...:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
   <li>List 1-1</li>
   <li>List 1-2</li>
   <li>List 1-3</li>
   <li>List 1-4</li>
   <li class="emptyMessage">This is empty</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li>List 2-1</li>
  <li>List 2-2</li>
  <li>List 2-3</li>
  <li>List 2-4</li>
  <li class="emptyMessage">This is empty</li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

in the `console`, I got the next errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { :3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery_ujs.js:429
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.purr.js:162
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined best_in_place.js:561
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined workers.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined application.js:19
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I think all the errors are because of jquery.js.

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to declare it before `doc ready`

if you don't have `jQuery plugin` attached before this script then these amends won't work, so try to include `jQuery` first then this script:

`And if you use cdn hosted script then page load performance will boostup.`

little amends to take care of:

```
$(document).ready(function{
   //--------------------^----missing braces '()'
```

it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

if this doesn't solve try declaring above this line

```
jQuery = $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

you need this order:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: @Shyam K Is OP mentioned it? don't you see the error in the `doc ready`?

Comment: have you included the jquery before your script?

Comment: yes: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="assets/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Okay! have you tried the last example in the answer? `jQuery = $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){`

Comment: OOPS just got that you are using `.sortable()` this is a function of `jquery-ui` you need to include that too. just below the jquery plugin.

Comment: @ShyamK see the new comment.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery_ujs.js:429
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.purr.js:162
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined best_in_place.js:561
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined workers.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: `$('#sortable1, #sortable2')` try this and see if this helps but remember to use this too: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22409/discussion-between-alon-shmiel-and-jai)

Answer (score 1):

You should also load the full jquery file, eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And changing the first two lines to the following is also a bit better:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#sortable1, #sortable2')
```

Comment: thank you. now, jsfiddle.net/8TCxY works, but I am still get the errors.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery_ujs.js:429
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.purr.js:162
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined best_in_place.js:561
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined workers.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined application.js:19

Answer (score 1):

include jquery in your HTML  BEFORE including your .js file

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then..

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: thank you. now I got the next errors: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery_ujs.js:429
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.purr.js:162
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined best_in_place.js:561
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined workers.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually load the JQuery library in your pages before you can use anything it defines. Without loading it, none of what you're trying to call has been defined anywhere, so there's nothing to call.

e.g. place the following before any other script tags:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Jai's answer regarding your syntax error is also correct in regards to that:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { :3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:1`

is being caused by the fact that you do not have parentheses following your function keyword in your anonymous function declaration.

The correct way to declare an anonymous function with no parameters is:

```
function () {
  //anonymous function routines/etc in here
}
```

So your first line would need to look like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

Comment: now, I got: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery_ujs.js:429
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.purr.js:162
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined best_in_place.js:561
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined workers.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined application.js:19

Comment: Yes, you have to make sure jquery is loaded BEFORE *all* scripts which depend on it. Where are these other scripts being referenced? Your script tag loading jquery needs to come before them.

Comment: can you invite me for chat and I will explain you please?

Comment: Sure, we can just continue with the room you started with Jai if you like.